# what are some phrases for "doing something evil in order to stop someone evil"

Tags: phrases, expressions

An example in real life would be killing a terrorist to stop him/her taking more innocent lives. What are some phrases that describe this situation?

Comment: Fight fire with fire.

Comment: "The end justifies the means" (Sergey Necheyev) can be traced back to Ovid's *Heroides*, and is widely associated with the Machiavelli. The branch of philosophy that handles such matters is called [consequentialism](https://www.google.com/search?q=consequentialism&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=consequentialism&aqs=chrome..69i57.6485j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: "To bite the bullet" is to do something unpleasant after some hesitation. Not a 100% match for what you ask but close.

Comment: *A blessing in disguise: something that seems bad or unlucky at first, but results in something good happening later* is close.

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly called a **necessary evil**.

From [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessary_evil)

> A **necessary evil** is an evil that someone believes must be done or accepted because it is necessary to achieve a better outcome—especially because possible alternative courses of action or inaction are expected to be worse. It is the "lesser evil" in the [lesser of two evils principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_of_two_evils_principle), which maintains that given two bad choices, the one that is least bad is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

yourdictionary.com

Retribution is defined as something done to get back at someone or the act of punishing someone for their actions. An example of retribution is when someone gets the death penalty for committing murder.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retribution

Retribution may refer to:

Punishment

**Retributive justice**, a theory of justice that considers proportionate punishment an acceptable response to crime

Divine retribution, retributive justice in a religious context

Revenge, a harmful action against a person or group in response to a grievance